# How to calculate a population weighted centroid using a raster and shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, centroids, population

I am very new to QGIS so please help me with a step by step answer.

I have a raster file with population count and a shapefile based on a large population and shapefile. I have successfully created the smaller raster and shapefiles for the region of interest. Now I just would like to find the population weighted centroid for this smaller region, and I don't know how (I know there is a related discussion, but it just provides the intuition and I don't know how to implement it in QGIS).

I have used the vector--> analysis tool --> mean coordinate(s), but no matter what I choose in the weight field, I always end up with the same point, so something should be wrong.

Also, do you know how I can find out to which map/variables the weight field values that are provided belong too?

Comment: The population data is a raster? Are you using the mean coordinates tool on the region shapefiles? What kind of result are you expecting to achieve that way? Also, which related discussion are you referring to? Please provide the link.

Comment: Hello, my population file is a raster file (each pixel represent a population size). I would like to know not where is the center of my region, but where is inverse population weight (average) center of my region. In other words, I would like the average/center of my area to be closer to where the population is.

Comment: Here is the link for the other discussion http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26425/generate-centroids-for-vector-polygons-based-on-raster-and-land-use-data-using-q