# Centre of mass w.r.t. a raster

Tags: qgis, centroids

I have a vector layer of polygons, and a raster layer with real numbers. I would like to get for each polygon, a 'centroid', not purely based on the geometry of the polygon (such as provided by Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Centroids), but based on the 'center of mass', where the equivalent of mass density is provided by the numbers in the raster layer.

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26425/160545) seems related, but is ten years old, and hopefully an easier solution is available now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking to get the center of population for each municipality in France. I didn't find any answer on stack exchange, so I have made my own and share it as an answer to your question.

First step transform your raster to a point layer. Use "raster pixel to point" in QGIS to do it.

Then join by location your point layer and your polygon layer to get a ID field for every point in each polygon.
[image]

Then use the tool "mean coordinate(s)" and choose your field use as weight and the field.

[image]

As a result you get your gravity center for every polygon, for my self it is the center of gravity of population for each municipality.

[image]

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that. However, converting to point layer, and processing that, was extremely slow in my case.

Comment: Indeed if your raster is big it could be long but as the QGIS core algo are optimized you can't find quicker solution. You may import your raster in a geopackage to get quicker conversion.